# What purpose does callback.bind() serve when returning a promise?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the source code of this [module](https://github.com/yeoman/update-notifier), I think I understood most of it but I don't understand this:

```
this.checkNpm().then(this.callback.bind(this, null)).catch(this.callback);
```

Why `.catch` isn't calling `.bind` as well?

Also `checkNpm()` returns a promise as well and also bound to `this`. What is `this` in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, what the module wanted to do was if `this.checkNpm` triggered `then` (i.e. was successful), then the author wanted to set the scope of the `this.callback` function to **the scope that this line was executed in.** Maybe the scope didn't matter if the function triggered catch, as all it might do is output some error. Remember that the `bind` function will return a function that will execute the original function in the context of the first argument (also the ability to set parameters, as seen here, but that's beside the point)

Hope this is clarifying